# Make UIView stretch vertically until a certain margin

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, constraints

I have a `UIView` where the content might overflow vertically, I set a vertical constraint (a height constraint, but top/bottom constraints have the same effect) to prevent the whole view (the pop up) from overflowing.

My goal is to have a view that takes up as much height as its content requires, up until it runs into pre-configured top and bottom margins from the edges of the screen (the safe areas).

My problem is, once I rotate the device to landscape and back to portrait, the popup doesn't stretch as much as it can vertically.

Things I already tried:

1. Setting a high priority to the height constraint.
2. setting a high compression resistance on the `itemView`.
3. Calling `layoutIfNeeded` after updating the constraints.
4. Creating another lower priority height constraint that tells the view to stretch the whole way.

Obviously none of these worked.

Initial state:

[image]

After rotating:

[image]

Rotating back to portrait:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
class PopupView: UIView, SpinnerProvider {
    lazy var spinner: SNSpinnerView = {
        let spinner = SNSpinnerView()
        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        spinner.spinnerImageView.image = spinnerImageDefault
        spinner.isHidden = false
        return spinner
    }()
    
    var itemView = UIView() {
        didSet {
            spinner.isHidden = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.animationDuration) {
                self.backgroundColor = .snDarkDimming
            }
            popupContainerView.addChild(itemView)
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    private lazy var popupContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.popUpFrameCornerRadius
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.accessibilityIdentifier = "popup"
        return view
    }()
        
    private lazy var containerHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        // Constant will change.
        popupContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 0)
    }()
    
    private lazy var containerLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        popupContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
    }()
    
    private lazy var containerTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        popupContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    }()
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        backgroundColor = .snLoadingViewBackground
        useAutoLayout()
        addSubview(popupContainerView)
        popupContainerView.useAutoLayout()
            .center(in: self)
        
        addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.useAutoLayout()
            .center(in: self)
        spinner.startRotationAnimation()
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerHeightConstraint,
            containerLeadingConstraint,
            containerTrailingConstraint
        ])
        
        adjustConstraints()
    }
    
    func adjustConstraints() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            containerLeadingConstraint.constant = Constants.Portrait.leadingInset
            containerTrailingConstraint.constant = Constants.Portrait.trailingInset
            containerHeightConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.height - (Constants.Portrait.horizontalInset * 2)
        } else {
            containerLeadingConstraint.constant = Constants.Landscape.leadingInset
            containerTrailingConstraint.constant = Constants.Landscape.trailingInset
            containerHeightConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (Constants.Landscape.horizontalInset * 2)
        }
    }
}
```

`adjustConstraints` is called from the parent view:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        popupView.adjustConstraints()
    }
```

Comment: What are the `UIScreen.main.bounds` values when you call `adjustConstraints()` when it works and when it doesn't? Should you check to `size` parameter of `viewWillTransition()`?

Comment: Don't use `UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait` ... instead, compare the superview's size. If height > width, consider it "portrait" orientation. That will help when the user is run-in your app on an iPad using multi-tasking. You didn't say what you intend to do when running full-screen on an iPad -- I would assume you'd want a "max" width/height? As a side note, it's very difficult to help figure out what might be wrong when we have to guess at so many things. Review [mre]

Comment: In addition to a less than or equal constraint, you need an equality constraint set to the maximum height but at a lower priority. This gives the view something to aim at.

Comment: Are you still looking for help on this? If so... assuming your "item view" will have a single-line/fixed-height "header label" + 3 fixed-height buttons + a variable-height "body" (such as a multiline label)... what should happen if it is too tall? Should the "body" text be truncated, as in your images? Or, maybe scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Your modally presented view is essentially under constrained. I answered somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77440268/4292657). Because it is under constrained, layout engine solves the layout one way during the initial load and then solves the layout another way when you return back to the portrait mode. When the view is under constrained or otherwise ambiguous, this is what happens.

If you properly constrain your views, then you won't have this problem. I replicated your view with the right set of constraints and strategic use of UIStackView. See the results below:

[image: Modal view with properly constrained views]

The [full solution](https://github.com/BenderNK/self-sizing-modal) is really long, so I will only post the most pertinent parts.

1. I started by creating a UIView with rounded-corners and white background. I call this the container view. I added this container view into the view controller's view as the only child.
2. Then this container view also has a single child: UIStackView with some padding around it.
3. I then embedded everything else in this StackView. In this example I have UILabel, UITexView, UIButton, UIButton, UIButton from top to bottom.
4. Make sure title label (RITM0010007) in the StackView has a fixed height. In my example, I have this height defined as 45 pts.
5. If you are using UITextView as the primary content, make sure it is not scrollable. You can either use UITextView or UILabel as the primary content. Do not define any constraints on this.
6. Make sure the buttons in the stack view also have height defined. I have them at 36 pts.
7. Make sure Stackview's alignment is fill.
8. Stackview takes care of the rest of the missing constraints.

This is how the container view was created in the code:

```
private func configureContainerView() {
    //containerView is declared at the view controller level
    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    containerView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    containerView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(containerView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}
```

This is how the stack view was created in the code:

```
private func configureStackView() {
    //primaryStackView is declared at the view controller level
    primaryStackView = UIStackView()
    primaryStackView.axis = .vertical
    primaryStackView.spacing = 16
    primaryStackView.alignment = .fill
    primaryStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.containerView.addSubview(primaryStackView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        primaryStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        primaryStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        primaryStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        primaryStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
    ])
}
```

Make sure rest of the contents are added to the stackview like so:

```
private func configureTitleView() {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    //configure title label
    primaryStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45)
    ])
}
```